# Get, Set, Read, converts bitwise in Short type value in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I have a short value X:

```
short X=1;  //Result in binary: 0000000000000001
```

1. I need to split them into an array and set the bits (say bit 6 and 10) //Result in binary: 0000001000100001
2. I need to convert it back to short X value.

How can I do it painlessly?
Could you please help?

Comment: Setting bits is a simple enough process, but I don't see the pattern behind retrieving the original short value afterwards. (Unless you will _always_ be setting the 6th and 10th bit.) I'm also not sure what you mean by "splitting them into an array".

Comment: Splitting into arrays is only a suggesion. do you have a nice aproch in mind how to solv ethis? I am a newbie

Comment: So do you need to be able to convert the post-changed short back to the original short or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are referring to is a very basic encryption, then perhaps using the XOR (`^`) operator would be better suited for your needs.

```
short FlipBytes(short original, params int[] bytesToSet)
{
    int key = 0;
    foreach (int b in bytesToSet)
    {
        if (b >= 0 && b < 16)
        {
            key |= 1 << b;
        }
    }

    return (short)(original ^ key);
}
```

This method will both set and reset the bytes that you desire. For example:

```
short X = 1;
short XEncrypt = FlipBytes(X, 6, 10);
short XDecrypt = FlipBytes(XEncrypt, 6, 10);

// X        = 1    , Binary = 0000000000000001
// XEncrypt = 1089 , Binary = 0000010001000001
// XDecrypt = 1    , Binary = 0000000000000001
```

Comment: @MongZhu I set the bits 6 and 10 if the first bit is regarded as bit 0. Presumably, OP regarded his first bit as bit 1. And regardless, that was an example that he gave, not a requirement. This still does the job that he needs.

Comment: @MongZhu I would say that bits are usually labeled starting as bit 0, because it lines up with the powers of 2 that they represent. (i.e. 2^0 = 1, 2^1 = 2, 2^2 = 4, etc.)

Comment: @Abion47 ok, you are right, the numbering of bits starts with zero, so OP numbered it wrong comparing to his expected output.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Manual solution**

Setting bit 6 and 10:

```
myValue |= (1 << 6)|(1 << 10);
```

Clearing bit 6 and 10:

```
myValue &= ~((1 << 6)|(1 << 10));
```

**2. Use BitArray**

```
var bits = new BitArray(16); // 16 bits
bits[5] = true;
bits[10] = true;
```

Convert back to short:

```
var raw = new byte[2];
bits.CopyTo(raw, 0);
var asShort = BitConverter.ToInt16(raw, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a int value "intValue" and you want to set a specific bit at position "bitPosition", do something like:

`intValue = intValue | (1 << bitPosition);`

or shorter:

`intValue |= 1 << bitPosition;`

If you want to reset a bit (i.e, set it to zero), you can do this:

`intValue &= ~(1 << bitPosition);`

(The operator ~ reverses each bit in a value, thus ~(1 << bitPosition) will result in an int where every bit is 1 except the bit at the given bitPosition.)

Answer (score 0):

*Linq* solution, terser, but probably, less readable than `foreach` loop:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  short X = 1;
  var bitsToSet = new[] { 5, 9 };

  var result = X | bitsToSet.Aggregate((s, a) => s |= 1 << a);
```

If you insist on `short` add *cast*:

```
  short result = (short) (X | bitsToSet.Aggregate((s, a) => s |= 1 << a));
```

Comment: This could be simplified by using the overload of `Aggregate` and setting `X` to be the initial seed. e.g. `bitsToSet.Aggregate(X, (s, a) => s |= 1 << a);`

Comment: @Abion47: `X` is of type `short` when `1 << a` is of type `int`, that's why we have to add *cast*: `bitsToSet.Aggregate(X, (s, a) => s |= (short) (1 << a));`